# How Dynamic insert jsp body to tiles 1.1

Tags: java, tiles, struts-1

I use struts 1 and tiles 1.1 in project.
I want define 1 tiles in struts and pass jsp body to tiles with java code.
Instate of  define many tiles similar

```
<definition name="a1" extends="layout">
        <put name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/x1.jsp"/>
</definition>
<definition name="a1" extends="layout">
        <put name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/x2.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

define

```
<definition name="dynamicTiles" extends="layout"/>
```

and used similar code in java controller

```
TilesUtil.getDefinition("dynamicTiles",
     getRequest(),getServlet().getServletContext())
.putAttribute("body","/WEB-INF/pages/x1.jsp");
```

It's work!! but in attribute of dynamicTiles lasted jsp add in body attribute.
Attribute is tile ComponentDefinition object is map and not released attribute in other request.
An other request new body add to map attribute.
it's completely work!! **but I worry about concurrent user problem in webApp**.
**Is this Correctly work??**

Answer (score 0):

I 's work but problem in tiles when use dynamic include.!!!

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it's now working with the tiles, but fails when you are using the dynamic include. Is that right? If so, does that solve your problem, or do you need the dynamic include to work? (From the question, it seems like the dynamic include is part of your requirement.)